# Memory Allocation Problems with structure

Tags: c++, memory-management, structure

- Why does the provided code crash at the following line?

  ```
  data *fillA = (data*)calloc(matrixa->nzmax, sizeof(data));
  ```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct csr
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int nzmax;
    int *rowPtr;
    int *colInd;
    double *values;
};

struct data
{
    int entry;
    int index;
};
bool descend(const data &a, const data &b)
{
    return a.entry > b.entry;
}

static bool ascend(const data &a, const data &b)
{
    return a.entry < b.entry;
}

void csrtranspose(struct csr *matrixa)
{

    int i, j, counter;
    double *tArray = NULL;
    data *fillA = (data*)calloc(matrixa->nzmax, sizeof(data));//fails here
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixa->nzmax; i++)
    {
        fillA[i].entry = matrixa->colInd[i];
        fillA[i].index = i;
    }
    sort(fillA, fillA + matrixa->nzmax, ascend);
    tArray = (double*)calloc(matrixa->nzmax, sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixa->nzmax; i++)
    {
        tArray[i] = matrixa->values[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixa->nzmax; i++)
    {
        matrixa->colInd[i] = fillA[i].entry;
        matrixa->values[i] = tArray[fillA[i].index];
    }
    free(tArray);
    free(fillA);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct data *total = 0;
    struct csr *s = 0;
    int nrows = 6, ncols = 5, counter = 0, nzmax = 10, rows = 3, cols = 5;
    double values[10] = {0.2135, 0.8648, 7, 0.3446, 0.1429, 6, 0.02311, 0.3599, 0.0866, 8 };
    int rowPtr[4] = { 0, 3, 6, 10 };
    int colInd[10] = { 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4 };
    s = (struct csr*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct csr));
    s->rows = rows;
    s->cols = cols;
    s->nzmax = nzmax;
    s->rowPtr = (int*)calloc(s->rows + 1, sizeof(int));
    s->colInd = (int*)calloc(s->nzmax, sizeof(int));
    s->values = (double*)calloc(s->nzmax, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        s->colInd[i] = colInd[i];
        s->values[i] = values[i];
        if (i <= s->rows)
        {
            s->rowPtr[i] = rowPtr[i];
        }
    }
    csrtranspose(s);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use malloc in C++. You can use `new` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: This looks a lot more like C than C++.

Comment: Why not `data *fillA = new data[matrixa->nzmax];`?

Comment: @Barry I think you mean, why not `std::vector<data> fillA(matrixa->nzmax);`

Comment: There *are* reasons why you might want to use C allocation routines in C++, but in general, `new` and `delete` (and `new[]` and `delete[]`) should be your "go to" allocation tools. But also in C++, look to using `std::vector` or other collections *first* before looking to dynamic allocation.

Comment: I know I can use new but a reason why this fails would be great for understanding the problem

Comment: It is 10 as shown in the main function

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `(double*)calloc(s->nzmax, sizeof(int));` in itself is a good reason to switch to C++ allocation, where it's impossible to make that mistake even if you copy-and-paste.

You're allocating too little memory and writing out of bounds.

Since all your sizes are known at compile time, you don't really need dynamic allocation at all.

Comment: hehe, I beat you by 2 seconds.

Comment: Such a stupid stupid stupid mistake. It was part of a big code

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it crashes there is because memory has already been corrupted by previously faulty code.  So, the problem is not there where it crashes, the problem is in code which executed earlier.

Specifically, this line:

```
s->values = (double*)calloc(s->nzmax, sizeof(int));
```

Allocates doubles, but uses `sizeof(int)`, so it does not allocate enough memory.

EDIT

Recommendations:

1. As others have already pointed out, when working with C++, use the `new` operator instead of C-style memory allocation.  It will save you from LOTS of problems.
2. If you insist on using C-style allocation, never use `p = (type*)malloc( sizeof(type) )`, always use `p = (type*)malloc( sizeof( *p ) )`.  This will at least make it more evident when you make the very common mistake of allocating memory for the wrong type.

Comment: @VineetYadav Do not worry, it happens even to the best. Be sure to read the recommendations that I added to my answer, so as to reduce the chances of such mistakes happening in the future.